# Download Google Sheet data as JSON from browser through custom menu

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apps

Is there a way to download JSON directly from a Google Sheet, like this:
[image]

I want to create a custom menu with an App Script. There would be a button that would create the JSON object from the sheet data and when it is finished it would download it immediately as a file.
So there is no GDrive or other apps involved, just a Google Sheet and an App Script.

Is this somehow possible to do? I could not find anything like this.

Comment: Show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I could not provide any of the search efforts because all the results were included GDrive integration. Anyway, @tanaike solved my issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe your goal as follow.

- You want to run the script from the custom menu.
- You want to download the active sheet as a file including a JSON data.
- The sample JSON data is as follows.

  - `[{"a1": "a2", "b1": "b2"},{"a1": "a3", "b1": "b3"},,,]`

In this case, in order to download a file, it is required to use Javascript. For this, in this answer, a dialog is used. So the flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Run the script from the custom menu.
2. A dialog is opened.
3. Javascript is run on the dialog, and the file is downloaded.
4. The dialog is closed.

When above flow is reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and run `onOpen` or reopen the Spreadsheet. By this, the custom menu is created.

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor as the Google Apps Script.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Menu').addItem('Export to JSON', 'download').addToUi();
}

function download() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
}

function downloadFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const [header, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const obj = values.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => Object.assign(o, {[header[j]]: c}), {}));
  const filename = `${sheet.getSheetName()}.txt`;
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(obj), MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT, filename);
  return {data: `data:${MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT};base64,${Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes())}`, filename: filename};
}
```

#### HTML&Javascript side: `index.html`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor as the HTML.

```
<script>
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(({ data, filename }) => {
    if (data && filename) {
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.download = filename;
      a.href = data;
      a.click();
    }
    google.script.host.close();
  })
.downloadFile();
</script>
```

### References:

- [Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I guess the dialog is necessary and could not be circumvented somehow?

Comment: @marchello Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. In order to download a file, it is required to use Javascript. By this, I proposed to use a dialog. For example, when you modify to `const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").setWidth(1).setHeight(1);`, the small size dialog is used. And, in your case, you can also use the sidebar instead of the dialog. But, it is required to run the Javascript. So the dialog and sidebar are required to be used. It seems that this is the current specification of Google side. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: You don't have to apologize, you are the one helping me out :) So thanks, I'll use then the "minified" dialog.

Comment: @marchello Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.