# Download all Google sheets charts in one shot?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I have a sheet that has more than 30 charts and my employees need to download all charts every hour, around 24/7 which takes much time for them. so my question is, is there is any way to download all charts in the sheets with one click or in an automated way?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from `is there is any way to download all charts in the sheets with one click or in an automated way?`. Can I ask you about the detail of both your current issue and your goal?

Comment: the current issue is that my team is working on hourly performance for the agents and we have many teams and we have charts for performance and quality so the total charts that need to be downloaded and sent to each team are around 30 charts which translates to 30 downloads to each chart image. so this is happening every hour for 24 hours for the whole day which is 24 hours across week, month, year. so imagine if each hour takes 5 minutes to just download this will result in 120 mins or 2 hours a day, in a month this will cost us 14 hours per week, 60 hours per month.

Comment: I know that I can add the charts to Google slides and export them as pdf, but the managers wouldn't prefer that idea that much

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your replying, about `30 downloads to each chart image`, in this case, do you want to download the 30 PNG images to the local PC? For example, do you want to download a zipped file including the 30 PNG images? And, what is `cant do export it to pdf neither` and `I can add the charts to Google slides and export them as pdf`, which do you want to download the 30 charts as PNG images or a PDF file?

Comment: And, where do you want to download the files to? Which is Google Drive or a local PC?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed 2 patterns. When those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: i really dont know how to thank you for your sincere help. thank you so much.

Comment: what i wanted to do is just download the charts in the page as png to local PC as zipped file or just as images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve all charts from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to download all chart images as a PDF file.
- From your following replying, I understood like above

  ```
    > the current issue is that my team is working on hourly performance for the agents and we have many teams and we have charts for performance and quality so the total charts that need to be downloaded and sent to each team are around 30 charts which translates to 30 downloads to each chart image. so this is happening every hour for 24 hours for the whole day which is 24 hours across week, month, year. so imagine if each hour takes 5 minutes to just download this will result in 120 mins or 2 hours a day, in a month this will cost us 14 hours per week, 60 hours per month.

    > I know that I can add the charts to Google slides and export them as pdf, but the managers wouldn't prefer that idea that much
  ```

But, from your question and replying, I couldn't understand where you want to download the PDF file to? So in this answer, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

1. Download chart images as a PDF to Google Drive.
2. Download chart images as a PDF to a local PC.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the chart images are downloaded as a PDF to Google Drive. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. In this case, when `myFunction()` is run, the PDF file is downloaded to Google Drive.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const outputFilename = "sample.pdf";

  // 1. Retrieve all charts in a Google Spreadsheet.
  const charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().flatMap(s => s.getCharts());

  // 2. Create new Google Slides as a temporal file.
  const s = SlidesApp.create("temp");

  // 3. Put the charts to each slide.
  let slide = s.getSlides()[0];
  slide.getShapes().forEach(e => e.remove());
  charts.forEach((c, i, a) => {
    slide.insertSheetsChart(c).alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.CENTER);
    if (i < a.length - 1) slide = s.appendSlide();
  });
  s.saveAndClose();

  // 4. Output Google Slides as a PDF data.
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(s.getId());
  DriveApp.createFile(file.getBlob().setName(outputFilename));
  
  // 5. Remove the temporal file of Google Slides.
  file.setTrashed(true);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the chart images are downloaded as a PDF to a local PC. This method is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66308417/7108653). In this case, when `download()` is run, the PDF file is downloaded to the local PC using Javascript on the opened dialog.

But, in this pattern, it is required to run the script by the user on browser. Because Javascript is used on the browser. Please be careful this.

#### `Code.gs`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet as a script.

```js
function download() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
}

function downloadFile() {
  const outputFilename = "sample.pdf";

  // 1. Retrieve all charts in a Google Spreadsheet.
  const charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().flatMap(s => s.getCharts());

  // 2. Create new Google Slides as a temporal file.
  const s = SlidesApp.create("temp");

  // 3. Put the charts to each slide.
  let slide = s.getSlides()[0];
  slide.getShapes().forEach(e => e.remove());
  charts.forEach((c, i, a) => {
    slide.insertSheetsChart(c).alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.CENTER);
    if (i < a.length - 1) slide = s.appendSlide();
  });
  s.saveAndClose();

  // 4. Output Google Slides as a blob of PDF data.
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(s.getId());
  const blob = file.getBlob().setName(outputFilename);
  
  // 5. Remove the temporal file of Google Slides.
  file.setTrashed(true);

  // 6. Return data as base64.
  return {data: `data:${MimeType.PDF};base64,${Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes())}`, filename: outputFilename};
}
```

#### `index.html`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet as HTML.

```js
<script>
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(({ data, filename }) => {
    if (data && filename) {
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.download = filename;
      a.href = data;
      a.click();
    }
    google.script.host.close();
  })
.downloadFile();
</script>
```

### Note:

- The above pattenrs are the simple sample scripts. So please modify them for your actual situation.

### References:

- [getCharts()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcharts)
- [insertSheetsChart(sourceChart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertsheetschartsourcechart)- [Custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)
- Related thread

  - [Download Google Sheet data as JSON from browser through custom menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66308153)

Comment: this one brilliantly works as charm. thank you so much but i ll be so thankful if we can download the charts as images in zipped file please. thank you so much for the effort and time taken to create this scripts.

Comment: @Redz85 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Unfortunately, although I'm not sure the pattern you wanted to use, when you want to export the images as a zip file, please output the images as the blobs and zip them using `Utilities.zip()`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#zipblobs,-name)

Comment: thank you so much, can you please explain where i should the code in the ref page? im sorry im terribly noob with javascript and coding :(

Comment: @Redz85 Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that the PNG images can be retrieved from all charts using one line script like `DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.zip(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().flatMap(s => s.getCharts().map(c => c.getBlob().setName(c.getOptions().get("title") + ".png")))).setName("sample.pdf"))`. When this script is run, a zip file is created on root folder of Google Drive.

Comment: thank you so much @Tanaike its working perfectly, you saved me and my team huge amount of time. have a blessed life <3